# 3D rotating animated panel that shows up after click on a menu link

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I need to realize an effect very similar to this included in [Kartell.com](http://www.kartell.com/it), clicking on varoius links, especially "*FollowUs*" and "*Search*".

It is a 3D rotation of a DIV that push to bottom following content.

I tried to investigate its code with inspector but I did not find a plugin that makes effect this possible, maybe could be a custom solution.

I tried to find something similar but the nearest I found is [3D Rotating Navigation](http://codyhouse.co/gem/3d-rotating-navigation/) that anyway is more complex that I need.

In brief, I need only to:

1. Click a link
2. A DIV will show with a 3D rotating effect (like
   kartell.com)
3. In this DIV I have a search form or alternative a list
   of social links, exactly the same as linked website.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You want effect similar to the kartell or any customization needed?

Comment: My customer practically asks me to reproduce panel that open when you click on "FollowUS" and "Search". In those panel, I'll reproduce also the same search form or social links list. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the webpage 3D Rotating Navigation everything is explained (just scroll down a bit).

```
/* enable a 3D-space for children elements */
perspective: 1000px;
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

And some docs about the perspective css attribute
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp

So basicly

1) Catch the click
2) Add a class like `div-3d-rotate` or something to the div you want to 3D rotate when clicked

You should use the tranisition, perspective and transform css properties.

You also need an extra div that wraps the div that you want to rotate. it should have a transition to handle the height.

Some sort of example: http://jsfiddle.net/cncpv83a/6/

Comment: I read documentation on plugin page but is not a real tutorial, only some details about the specific plugin and no informations about JS code. 
I know how to apply a `CSS rotation` to an element, but here the problemi is more complex because `CSS transformations` don't affect position of other elements in page, and they continue to fill the original space, not pushing up and down other content... and obviously in my cas I have to mantain open the panel when digiting in it search terms, not auto-close like linked plugin

Comment: Look at my simple example above. I don't know what your plans are exactly, but in my fiddle you can see how to apply a simple animation to an html element.

Comment: When user clicks the trigger element, the class .nav-is-visible is added to the <main>, <header> and <nav> elements which are translated of a quantity equal to the navigation height while the .cd-3d-nav is rotated back (rotateX(0))

so i guess it can be done in pure css

Comment: @SanderVisser: so, are you suggesting not to integrate this plugin but to take only CSS code?

Comment: Yes, the menu should be wrapped and the wrapper should get an extra class on the trigger. That div should handle the height (so not the rotating div)

Comment: That's how I would to it. On the 3D Rotating page, they add the class also to the content and they move the content down. I'm going to make a JSFiddle

Comment: a JSFille could be a perfect help, thank you. Please, consider desired behaviour that is a little different from plugin demo. Panel should open under navigation menu and pushing down content like if this panel would be another face of an hypotetic cube in which front face is the page content and the upper face is the panel that should be opened. thanks :-)

Comment: I don't have that much time haha, but here you go https://jsfiddle.net/cncpv83a/3/   it could use some improvements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cncpv83a/6/  this one is better because of the locked position (the absolute positioned div)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a link and a panel.
The click handler on the links adds a 'active' or 'shown' class to the panel.

The panel is initialized with width and height 0 and need to apply transitions to the panel. The css for the 'shown' or 'active' class makes a transform with an rotation.

HTML:

```
<div class="invoke">Invoke</div>
<div class="panel">
  Yes this is the panel
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.invoke').click(function(){
  $(".panel").addClass("show");
});
```

CSS:

```
.panel{
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   margin: 100px;
   background-color: #ff0000;
   /* Firefox */
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   /* WebKit */
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   /* Opera */
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   /* Standard */
   transition: all 1s ease;
 }

.panel.show{
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   /* Firefox */
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   /* WebKit */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
   /* Opera */
   -o-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
   /* Standard */
   transform: rotate(360deg) ;
 }
```

See my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cncpv83a/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the effect is completely different from what I asked for. Please, click on "FollowUs" and "Search" links on [Kartell.com](http://www.kartell.com) to see exactly what I need